# Determine path to executable

Tags: ros, path, rosrun, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to determine the absolute path to a binary I built. With `rospack find` I can get the path to the package itself. However, finding the path to the executable is much harder: In the devel workspace it usually is in `<workspace>/devel/lib/<project>` but when the package is deployed and installed to `${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}` it is located directly in `<install prefix>/<project>/`.

In both cases I can run that binary with `rosrun <package> <binary>` but I did not find a way to get the corresponding path.
Is there a portable way to get the absolute path to a binary?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209051/determine-path-to-executable/) by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 152 on 2015-05-12

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-05-12**:
I can think of a "portable" way for this.. Why would you want to to this? Maybe there is another workaround for your problem!?

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2015-05-12**:
Portable here means "working for both development workspaces as well as installed packages." I do not loke workarounds where I have to add if/else clauses at every place where I want to get the absolute path to my binary.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2015-05-12**:
Still, want do you intent to do with the path? Usually you do not need to know the path as rosrun and roslaunch do locate the file for you!

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2015-05-12**:
I want to run the binary by using the absolute path. I have to run the binary as quickly as possible as we measure the elapsed time of certains tasks. For that reason I want to avoid rosrun as it traverses the whole filesystem (I assume via `rospack find`, which can be relatively slow).

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-05-13**:
`catkin_find` uses a similar logic as tools like `rospack`. It also needs to crawl the filesystem.

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2015-05-13**:
Ok, thanks. Yes, `catkin_find` works for me, but only if I sourced all devel workspaces, while rosrun apparently finds its packages via `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default the location of the executable should be the same:

- `<devel_space>/lib/<pkg_name>/<executable_name>`
- `<install_space>/lib/<pkg_name>/<executable_name>`

If it is not in your case may be it helps to post your CMake file to provide more information.

Anyway you should be able to find your executable by invoking:
`catkin_find <pkg_name> <executable_name>`

You can narrow down the search with various options (see `catkin_find --help`).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2015-05-12**:
Thank you for your answer. I will have a look and try `catkin_find`. Is it only available in build environments or also for production/installed packages? I will also re-check why our package layout of the installed files is different to that of the `devel_space`.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-05-13**:
The executable is provided as part of the catkin package: see `which catkin_find` and `dpkg -S /opt/ros/indigo/bin/catkin_find`.

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2015-05-13**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2015-05-18**:
It works for me but only if the catkin `workspace/devel/setup.bash` was properly sourced. rosrun works all the time because it only relies on the path being in `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`. Thus the behaviour of `catkin_find` is not quite identical to `rosrun`.